# How to get max possible size of UIView

Tags: ios

I've a question about UIViews. How can I get the max possible size? The size without StatusBar, NavBar etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` will return the size of the device's screen in points.

Comment: But then I have to substract the size for toolbars additionally, haven't I?

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted. The _maximum_ size.